# neo4j counting relations of multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I work on neo4j graph , I wrote this query

```
    match (rec:Recipe) , (rec1:Recipe) , (rec)-[r:ContainsIngredient]->() , (rec1)-       [r1:ContainsIngredient]->()  
where rec.name = "a" AND rec1.name = "b"
return  count(r) , count(r1)
```

it returns the same value , although Recipe("a") have three relations and Recipe("b") have 5 relations .
note : I noticed that it always returns the bigger value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't grouping by the recipe name. Try this:

```
MATCH (rec:Recipe)
WHERE rec.name = "a" OR rec.name = "b"
MATCH (rec)-[:ContainsIngredient]->()
RETURN rec.name, COUNT(*)
```

Comment: alternatively `WHERE rec.name IN ['a','b']`

Comment: you can also merge the two matches into one